# Cannot multiply values from IntegerFields in django

Tags: python, django, user-interface, textfield

I am confused regarding how to multiply the values of two IntegerFields in django. I am relatively new to django so I might be missing something fairly obvious. My code gives me the following exception: 
"ValueError at /multiplication/multiplied
The view multiplication.views.post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST" 
Here is the code from my views.py:

```
       from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
       from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
       from django.template import RequestContext
       from django.views.generic import TemplateView
       from django import forms
       from multiplication.forms import HomeForm

       template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'
       template_name2 = 'multiplication/multiplied.html'

       class myForm(forms.Form):
       quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
       quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

       form = myForm()

       def get(request):
           return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form} )
       def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
           return x*y

      def post(request):
          if (form.is_valid()):
             x = request.POST('quantity1')
             y = request.POST('quantity2')
             product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
             return render(request, template_name2, {'form': form, 
             'product': product })
```

Template 1:

```
             <h1>Multiplication Function</h1>
             <form action =  "{% url 'multiplication:post' %}" method = 
             "post">
             {{ form.as_p  }}
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input type = "submit" value ="Multiply">
             <!--<button type="submit"> Multiply </button>-->
             <h1>{{product}}</h1>
             </form>
```

Template 2:

```
             <h1>{{product}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your form is **not** valid, then the guard `if (form.is_valid())` doesn't pass and so the `post` function returns `None` instead of rendering an `HttpResponse` as it should.

Hence the nature of the exception.

Comment: How do I make the form valid?

Comment: Also even if the form was valid this will error: `request.POST('quantity1')`. `POST` is a dictionary-like object so you need to use `request.POST.get('quantity1')`.

Comment: You can interrogate what is wrong with the form by calling `form.errors`. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors

Comment: Thank you. I am just still confused regarding what I am supposed to do?